# Pandas all rows into one row of pd.series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame loaded from a csv file like below:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   -1.140625   -1.828125   0.671875    -1.031250   -0.390625   -0.203125
1   -1.203125   -1.843750   0.687500    -0.953125   -0.281250   -0.156250
2   -1.187500   -1.781250   0.656250    -0.843750   -0.218750   -0.171875
3   -1.125000   -1.640625   0.593750    -0.765625   -0.234375   -0.062500
4   -1.031250   -1.453125   0.531250    -0.718750   -0.265625   -0.093750
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
6968    -1.093750   -0.687500   0.062500    -1.156250   -0.281250   -0.156250
6969    -1.140625   -0.734375   0.109375    -1.343750   -0.046875   -0.093750
6970    -1.203125   -0.765625   0.156250    -1.234375   0.046875    -0.171875
6971    -1.234375   -0.812500   0.234375    -0.953125   0.171875    -0.093750
6972    -1.265625   -0.843750   0.281250    -0.828125   0.078125    -0.265625
6973 rows × 6 columns
```

And I want to squeeze all row elements into one row of pandas series.
The original dataFrame is 6973 rows of 6 columns with every cell having one digit data, and my desired output is 1 row of 6 columns, with every column having a sequence(series?) of length 6973

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   -1.140625 -1.203125 1.891651 2 1.939205 3...    0 -0.207383 1 -0.193249 2 -0.239664 3...    0 0.261557 1 0.235363 2 0.258561 3...   0 -0.214562 1 -0.249118 2 -0.291458 3...    0 -0.171253 1 -0.112890 2 -0.041053 3...    0 -0.118167 1 -0.112238 2 -0.102034 3...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with default index, convert to DataFrame and transpose:

```
df = df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame().T
```

Or use [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(df, order='F')])
```

EDIT:

You can convert all Series to lists by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{k: list(v) for k, v in df.items()}])
```

Comment: My original dataframe is 6973 rows by 6 columns, but I want to put all 6973 rows into one series. So my desired output is 1 row of 6 columns, with every column having series length of 6973

Comment: @jhl97 - It is impossible in pandas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this code seems to flatten my dataframe to 1 row with 41838 columns

Comment: @jhl97 - close, what need - `df = df.astype(str).agg(' '.join).to_frame().T`

Comment: @jhl97 - Or `df = pd.DataFrame([{k: list(v) for k, v in df.items()}])`, added to answer.